# link two fields select type symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

i work with Symfony2 and I want to see how I can use Form Events to link two fields select type.
The first field contains the cities and the second contains the country.

here is my entities:

```
user
  - id
  - name
  - IdCity

city
  - id
  - CityName
  - IdCountry

country
  - id
  - countryName
```

And thank you.

Comment: You want to select country and then city? And select element with cities is regenerated after country has been selected? I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

( *working without javascript , enhanced with javascript, no reload required, small city amounts* )

Create **one** select field of **entity field-type** displaying all cities and use **[group_by](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by)** to group by country.

- hide your single grouped select field with javascript ( type="hidden" )
- split the select fields with JavaScript into a country field for the groups and add a second one for cities
- change the city field if the country fires onchange event
- change the hidden field if the city field fires onchange event

This way you are saving the code necessary to create a second form, inject your current country, filter with a second queryBuilder ... If you do have a lot of cities ( even with a cached result you are outputing too many )... go for solution #2.

### Solution #2

( *huge amount of cities, therefore loading cities filtered by country selection required* )

- create a form with an entity field type for the countries
- pass the currently selected country into your form - default to null ( i.e. from your action or inject the request and read it from there)
- create a subform of entity field type for the cities
- if the selected country read from request is null - don't add the subform to the builder
- if present -> add the subform and use the queryBuilder city field-type to filter the cities by country
- enhance by AJAX-loading the subform on country-select

Hope you get the idea :)